# How to localize a custom fee label in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, localization, cart

I need to do some job in Wordpress. I managed to add fee to checkout

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'thebestcompany_service', $fee, true, 'standard' );
```

That's great. I managed to create a plugin. That's great. I managed to translate my plugin with **Loco translate**. That's great.

But I do not now where to translate the fee `thebestcompany_service`.

There is no such string in the plugin translation, in theme translation or woocommerce plugin translation. Please help.

Comment: I suppose your answer is correct but I can not get back to this job due to lack of time. I will return to this task on saturday and I remember to write feedback here. Yes I understand here are some civility rules and it's a good manner to mark responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make The string translatable in your function, you need to use [**a translatable function**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) this way:

```
$fee_label = __( 'The best company service', 'domain_name' );
// Or (without domain name):
// $fee_label = __( 'The best company service' );

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee, true, 'standard' );
```

*Where `'domain_name'` has to be replaced by your active theme domain slug or plugin domain slug, that Loco translate is going to use.*

This should work now